# WinForms Multiline TextBox: how to paint small image in the corner of TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, ownerdrawn

I have a WinForms App, C#, .NET 4.0.

I have a `Multiline` `TextBox` on a `Form`.
Except usual text and `TextBox` itself, I'd like to see a triangle in the corner of `TextBox`:

[image]

To do that I override WndProc method of `TextBox` in the following way:

```
        private const int WM_PAINT = 0x000f;
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_PAINT:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    paintInnerButton();
                    break;
                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void paintInnerButton()
        {
            Point innerButtonLocation = ClientRectangle.Location + (ClientSize - UITools.InnerButtonSize);
            var innerButtonRect = new Rectangle(innerButtonLocation, UITools.InnerButtonSize);
            drawTriangle(CreateGraphics(), BackColor, innerButtonRect.Location);
        }

        private static void drawTriangle(Graphics gr, Color backColor, Point location)
        {
            Color innerButtonColor = _activeInnerButtonColor;

            Point[] points = {
            new Point(location.X, location.Y + InnerButtonSize.Height), // LEFT BOTTOM
            new Point(location.X + InnerButtonSize.Width, location.Y), // RIGHT TOP
            new Point(location.X + InnerButtonSize.Width, location.Y + InnerButtonSize.Height) // RIGHT BOTTOM
        };

            using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(
                new Point(
                    location.X + (int)(InnerButtonSize.Width / 2.0),
                    location.Y + (int)(InnerButtonSize.Height / 2.0)),
                new Point(location.X - 1 + InnerButtonSize.Width, location.Y + InnerButtonSize.Height),
                backColor,
                innerButtonColor
                ))
            {
                gr.FillPolygon(brush, points);
            }
        }
```

The problem comes, when there is long text and I press Down button on my keyboard to scroll it down. A few smaller triangles appear:

[image]

Any ideas, why does that happen and how to overcome it?

Comment: You cannot get this reliable.  TextBox commits a crime that dates back to the 1980s when Windows had to run on a 386sux machine.  It paints without using WM_PAINT.  This defeats any attempt at ownerdraw.  Something hokey like a transparent toplevel window that overlays the control can be made to work.

Answer (score 0):

First of, you should dispose your graphics

```
using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
{
    drawTriangle(g, BackColor, innerButtonRect.Location);
}
```

And although, drawing a textbox can be tricky, for your specific problem, I would modify your `WndProc()` to `Refresh()` your control (it will force the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself) on the following windows messages `WM_VSCROLL`, `WM_HSCROLL` or `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`. As follows:

```
    private const int WM_PAINT = 0x000f;
    private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x114;
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
    private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20A;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_PAINT:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                paintInnerButton();
                break;
            case WM_VSCROLL:
            case WM_HSCROLL:
            case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
                this.Refresh();
                break;
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
```